# Differentiating between the windows and ubuntu drive space

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I am installing ubuntu for the first time. I followed the instructions online and created a usb disk for the install on my Acer Aspire One netbook. My netbook came with windows preloaded and I am wary of completely removing windows since this is my first time with ubuntu.  I am currently in the middle of the install right now, how do I differentiate between the drive space allocated for ubuntu and the drive space allocated for windows?

The installation program has what I can only assume is the optimum drive allocation at 70/30 but I want to be sure which is which. Help?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to AskUbuntu!

When setting up a dual boot system, you will have one existing NTFS partition for Windows and will be resizing it to add an ext4 partition and a swap partition for Linux. NTFS, ext4, and swap are just names for the types of partitions.

When you install Ubuntu, Windows will not be able to recognize the partition (the part of the disk) that Ubuntu is installed on. Windows will recognize that Ubuntu partitions exist, but will not be able to tell you what type they are, or read and write data to them. There are a couple ways you can access Linux partitions from Windows, like with the free programs [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs), [DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/), or the [Ext2 File System for Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html).

Ubuntu, however, will recognize your Windows partition, and you will be able to "mount" it, read and write data to it. Upon login, you will see a link on your desktop to access your Windows partition, and there will be a sidebar entry in the file manager for easy access. Upon opening it, you can explore much of the user data in the "Users" folder.

Upon boot, you will see a menu with the option to boot from Linux or Windows, with a couple of other options (which happen to be on your Linux partition) for diagnostic purposes.

In Ubuntu, you can install GParted. This will allow you to view a simple visualization of the layout of your disk partitions, and has quite a few tools for manipulating them as well. You will only want to manipulate your partitions when making more free space, installing other operating systems, or doing other system-related tasks.

Good luck with Ubuntu! I hope your experience is a good one. It's great, here in the Linux world.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice the bug that @Seth mentioned. Hopefully you'll find some of this info useful.